# Copy and paste data in a new sheet after clearing the filter in another sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The new sheet **did not** display the whole data after I click "All" button **once** to display all the data in new sheet after clearing the filter. However, it only shows the whole data when I click "All" button **twice**.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Reset1_button()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LRow As Long

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("SALES").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
LastRow = LastRow + 1
LRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("ONE_ALLIANZ_REPORT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 18)
LRow = LRow + 1

Range("A19:AQ" & LRow).Clear
Sheets("SALES").Select

If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

Sheets("SALES").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AQ" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets("ONE_ALLIANZ_REPORT").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @HanaVarsy, Welcome to SO, I would suggest you to avoid `Select`

Comment: Read and apply [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to your code. If your issue is still there, please [edit] your question and udpate the code to the new code (without select).

Comment: Thanks !! You just saved my life :)

Comment: @HannaVarsy May I ask you to accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57993018/11167163) . Please look [Here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this code and tell me if your issue is solved, i think that `select` was the issue.

Also please note that `Thisworkbook` appoint the workbook where the macro is coded

```
Sub Reset1_button()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LRow As Long

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
LastRow = LastRow + 1
LRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ONE_ALLIANZ_REPORT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 18)
LRow = LRow + 1

Range("A19:AQ" & LRow).Clear

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").FilterMode Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").ShowAllData
End If


 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").Range("A3:AQ" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ONE_ALLIANZ_REPORT").Range("A19")

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").AutoFilterMode And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").FilterMode) Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").FilterMode Then` is the same as `If  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SALES").FilterMode Then`

Comment: FWIW, you can do the copy paste in one go to avoid filling the clipboard (and the use of `CutCopyMode`). Resizing `A19` would be an alternative.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ and jvdV I edited the code thanks to your suggestion